# Starting Steam games by typing the path - where are they?

Tags: command-line, steam

I use`/./usr/bin/applicationname` to launch programs using terminal, but steam games (and steam) don't show up in it, although I can put a steam game in my favorite applications list. Is there any way to find it?

Answer (score 4):

Steam games are installed by default in directories under `/home/<user>/.steam/steam/steamapps/common`, where `<user>` is your username. For example, if you have Europa Universalis IV installed, you can start it from the terminal using `/home/<user>/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Europa\ Universalis\ IV/eu4`.

The Steam binary is located by default at `/usr/games/steam`. It should be in your `$PATH` (the shell variable defining the places that the shell searches for binaries), so you can find it using `which steam` and you can run it by simply entering `steam`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me launch steam, but your method for launching games gives me the error: /home/keithosterheld/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/robocraft: No such file or directory

Comment: Does `/home/keithosterheld/.steam/steam/steamapps/common` exist? You could also try `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common`, using `~` as a shortcut to your home directory. 

If that doesn't work, you might want to take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227502/where-are-steam-games-installed).

Comment: Yes, it says that is a directory. If I ls it it says robocraft (the game I'm trying to launch) is in there, but when I try adding /robocraft to the end it says the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I've figured it out now. For anyone else who wants to do this, you type `ls ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/<name of app you want to launch>`.
I saw a few files, two of which were `<app name>.x86` and `<app name>.x86_64`

The latter one worked for me, but I think the other one would work for 32 bit applications.