# Going to re-install ubuntu, how to backup my steam

Tags: backup, games, steam

My Ubuntu is now a mess..
after I switch my graphic card driver to fglrx (I don't really understand what is it)
its really mess my whole computer, so i need to re-install my Ubuntu..
therefore, I need to backup my steam includes all of my steam games,
how can I do that?
and after backup all those file, how can i restore it?
I really cant help to re-download those so many gigabytes files..
thanks for the help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are Steam games installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227502/where-are-steam-games-installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default steam libary is in `~/.local/share/Steam`. I'm not sure if it's possible to change but if you changed it you would know where it is.

Comment: can I copy those file to my flash disk, and after re-install my Ubuntu, I just need to place those folders back?

Comment: @AdiYono Well I think so. You might have to click on download but it will  finish instantly.