# Steam Rom Manager: incorrect Steam directory

Tags: steam, emulation

Anyone able to help with [Steam Rom Manager](https://github.com/doZennn/steam-rom-manager.git)

Application is throwing this error on Ubuntu 19.10:

```
Warning! No user accounts found, it could be due to one of the reasons below:

incorrect Steam directory;
no user has ever logged in;
Steam does not save user credentials ("Show advanced options -> User accounts -> Use account credentials").
If you're seeing this, preview won't be generated for this configuration.
```

Directory I'm using is

```
/usr/bin/steam
```

Comment: `/usrr/bin/steam` is not directory, but path to binary file. https://askubuntu.com/q/227502/925971

Comment: Ok I kinda get that, any suggestions on where to find path or how to locate this directory I used which steam to come up with /usr/bin/steam

Comment: In my case it is in `~/.local/share/Steam`

Comment: Just tried ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam and that didn''t work either application error'ed on that without "Test Parser", when I went the other it accepted that.... I'm confused

Comment: where is steam gave me steam: /usr/bin/steam /usr/lib/steam /usr/games/steam /usr/share/man/man6/steam.6.gz

Comment: I do not use steam, but just installed it to answer some questions. I'll try now to follow your tutorial to see what will happen.

Comment: Thanks Help much appreciated

Comment: All good Gryu solved with ~/.local/share/Steam - Mark as Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct Steam directory for you (as you said in comment) is:

```
~/.local/share/Steam
```

But it is better to specify the full path:

```
/home/you_user/.local/share/Steam
```

To find all directories called `steam` or `Steam` you could use the next command:

```
sudo find / -type d -iname Steam 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

It would show only case insensitive (`-i` before `name`) directories (`-type d` option), hiding records with `Permission denied` message.

In my case it outputs:

```
/usr/lib/games/steam
/usr/lib/steam
/usr/share/doc/steam
/home/user/test/steam-rom-manager/src/lib/helpers/steam
/home/user/.local/share/Steam
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/steam
```

Doing `ls` of each directory, you could get theirs content. Appropriate folder would contain a lot of files and directories.