# Create steam library on Hard drive that's connected through ssh connected Network

Tags: networking, ssh, hard-drive, games, steam

I've just recently made the swap to Linux and I have been loving it.  I have 2 PCs, one for gaming, the other is a server.  I have steam games etc on the server hard drive (for Small/old single player games).

I am trying to create/connect a steam folder to that hard drive so I can install games to it but can't seem to find it in the directory.  I have connected and mounted it too.  I'm kinda lost and can't seem to get help online with it.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 Jellyfish

Cheers,

Comment: You are running either "Ubuntu 20.04 Focal" or "Ubuntu 22.04 Jellyfish". There is no "20.04 Jellyfish".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are Steam games installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227502/where-are-steam-games-installed). It's hard to tell which of the many possible folders/mount points/machines "it" refers to; you could edit your question to replace several instances of "it" with clearer nouns.